# Query somedata with 'null' value in database field by sails-disk mysql adapter or mysql in nodejs application

Tags: mysql, node.js, null, sails.js, mocha.js

I have a nodejs web application and a mocha unit test case. How can I update the name that contains lastname as null by using sails-disk mysql data adapter? for mysql query string is like $update user SET lastname ='aaa' where lastname is NULL;

```
it('Should get user.', function (done) {
    request(sails.hooks.http.app)
    .update('/user')
    .send({lastname: null})
    .expect(201)
    .end(function (err, res) {
        console.log(res.body;)
      done();
    });
});
```

after couple time trying, i realease the issue is mysql cannot get the data by query

```
it('should create a User', function (done) {
    request('/user')
    .send({ name: 'aaaa' })
        .expect(201)
    .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
        done();
    });
});
it('should get a User', function (done) {
    request('/user')
    .query({ name: 'aaaa' })
    .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
        done();
    });
});
it('should get a User', function (done) {
    request('/user')
    .query({ lastname: null })
    .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
        done();
    });
});
it('should get a User', function (done) {
    request('/user')
    .send({ lastname: null })
    .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
        done();
    });
});

{ name: 'aaaa',
  lastname: null,
  id: 2 }
    ✓ should create a User (62ms)
[ { name: 'aaaa',
    lastname: null,
    id: 2 }]
    ✓ should get a User
[]
    ✓ should get a User
[]
    ✓ should get a User
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ..by using sails-disk mysql data adapter

Sails-disk adapter is not for MySQL. Instead of this we have a [sails-mysql](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql)

To update model you should do this like this:

```
 User.update({lastname: "null"}, {lastname: new_user_name}).exec((err, updated_user) => {
   if (err) return  res.serverError();
   else if(!updated_user) return res.notFound("User doesn't exist!!!");
   else return res.ok();
 });
```

First parmetr of update() function is criteria for searching.
Second parametr of update() function is data for updating record.
And the last one is callback.

Here is more description: [update()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/update)

Comment: I do try to use sails-mysql too. however, it is too slow in codeship ci deployment environment